# Is this a bug of scipy RectBivariateSpline?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to do interpolation as below but the result is seemingly the result of a bug. I want to know if anyone had the same problem.

img: input image (numpy ndrarray) of h-by-w

img data looks like this:

[image]

The img contains 8-bit pixel intensity values and each element is divided by 256.0 before the interpolation. The img does not contain nans or infs.

```
from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline

h, w = img.shape
x = np.arange(0, h)
y = np.arange(0, w)
ip = RectBivariateSpline(x,y, img)
```

The code excerpt throws unhandled exception as below.

[image]

If I change from RectBivariateSpline to interp2d then the whole python crashes. The gist of the below dialog window is that python.exe crashed due to the module named '_fitpack.pyd'

[image]

I am working on Windows 7 64 bit and python 2.7 32-bit. numpy=1.6.2, scipy=0.11.0 and numpy.test() and scipy.test() both return 'OK'

If someone can tell me this is known (possibly reported) bug, I will have to think some other way to accomplish this task.

Comment: Does img have any invalid values (NaNs, Infs)?

Comment: Interesting point. I checked it with `np.nonzero(np.isnan(data) == True)` and it returns an emtpy array. Also with infs. So the img does not contain nans or infs. img is a gray scale 8-bit representation of an image. So I don't expect nans or infs are in it.

Comment: It is hard to further comment without seeing the data. Are you sure `img` is a numpy array? Perhaps try: `img = np.array(img)`.

Comment: img is loaded from a Matlab file with scipy.io.loadmat(). So it is dict type not ndarray. And I thought that you could be so right and  changed the type with `img = np.array(scipy.io.loadmat(data_filename)['data'])` but the result was the same.

Comment: I updated my question to add more description about img.

Comment: From the code in the traceback, it looks like the error occurs when you call `ip`, not when you call `RectBivariateSpline` to create `ip`.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Weckesser How did you know that?! It wasn't in the code that I provided you. So It wasn't the problem of RectBivariateSpline. However, interp2d DOES crash at `ip = interp2d(x, y, img)`

Comment: I am trying to convert Matlab's interp2(Z, XI, YI) to python with scipy. scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline returns `ip` in above code and it was indeed successful. However, the original Matlab source code specifies XI and YI in 2d matrices so I unquestioningly did the same thing as `zi = ip(xi, yi)` and the error above occurs.